# Self-similar solution of the second kind

Tags: differential-equations, non-linear-systems, invariants

I have a problem trying to understand the procedure for using self-similar solution of the second kind. More specifically, I was reading about an equation of this form,

$$\partial_t{d} + \frac{1}{r} \partial_r \left(\left(1+d\right)^3 \left(\partial^{2}_{r}d - \frac{1}{r}\partial_r d \right)\right) = 0$$

which is derived from Navier-Stokes equations.

It is proposed to write the solution as a product of 2 functions such :

$$d = d_0(t) F(U)$$

And with : $$U = \frac{r}{t^{1/4}(1+d_0)^{3/4}}$$

My question is : how can we assume this expression for $U$? If we inject the expression of $d$ in the main equation and because it is a non linear one, it is complicated to find a differential equation to determine $U$.

Could someone help with the procedure needed to deal with these kind of self-similar solutions?

Comment: *How can we assume this expression for U?* Are you asking how did somebody figure out that this assumption would be useful?

Comment: @Ghoster Usually, self-similar variable can be deduced analytically by introducing the self similar solution in the main equation but here I don't see how it is possible because of the non linearity. Is there something specific for self similar solutions of second kind that I am missing ?